# Office 2019 Professional Plus (Outlook Missing)

Tags: microsoft-office

I just installed Office 2019 Professional Plus from Microsoft Partner Network (Microsoft Action Pack). It only installed Word,Excel and Powerpoint. In control panel it shows Office 2019 home edition.

Why Outlook is missing?

I didn't enter my product key yet. Is other products like outlook are installing after entering product key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, now i understand whats the problem. In microsoft's partner site "Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2019" download link is wrong. It actually downloads Office 2019 home.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you have, according to Office365:

[Office Home & Student 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/office-home-student-2019/CFQ7TTC0K7C8?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab)

[image: Office Home & Student 2019]

Outlook is part of Office 365 plans such home, personal and business.

Comment: What i don't get is, when i'm installing from Microsoft's site it says "Office 2019 Professional Plus" but after installing it shows "Office 2019 Home Edition" in control panel. And again i didn't enter my product key yet.

Comment: Than perhaps the default without product key does not include Outlook, and entering the key will upgrade it?

Comment: @user2617750 try to log in with your microsoft account once you've installed your Office 2019.

Comment: Oh, now i understand whats the problem. In microsoft's partner site "Microsoft Office Pro Plus 2019" download link is wrong. It actually downloads Office 2019 home.

Comment: @Ronald - You indicated the author has Office 2019 Home and Student, but then indicate that Office is included in Office 2019 Home, but your screenshot clearly says otherwise  I am not entirely sure what you are trying to indicate is the answer.